# How to use ember cli with visual studio

Tags: ember.js, visual-studio-2013, ember-cli

I would like to use Ember with visual studio 2013.
First i [followed this](http://www.hutchinson.io/ember-cli-and-asp-net/) to set up the server/api, and create a new project, and If i try it on the Windows's console it works.

But If i try to run it in Visual Studio there are errors, first of all, the new directory that the command  `ember init` creates, is not visible in my visual studio project.

Second if I run it, i get this error:`HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden The server is not configured to ..`

The windows console's localhost and the Visual studio localhost are different. When I run `ember serve` I get the following:

```
version: 1.13.1
Livereload server on http://localhost:35729
Serving on http://localhost:4200/

Build successful - 19116ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
TreeMerger (appAndDependencies)               | 4043ms
TreeMerger (ExternalTree)                     | 3875ms
Concat: Vendor                                | 3533ms
TreeMerger (vendor)                           | 1524ms
Funnel                                        | 1161ms

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
TreeMerger (appAndDependencies) (1)           | 4043ms
TreeMerger (ExternalTree) (1)                 | 3875ms
Concat: Vendor (1)                            | 3533ms
Funnel (32)                                   | 2350ms (73 ms)
TreeMerger (vendor) (1)                       | 1524ms
```

Instead on Visual Studio I have this : http://localhost:63551/

What do I have to do to get an ember-cli project running with visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
As seen on github :
https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3746

> In short: Use the nodejstools, npm@3, ember-cli-windows, PowerShell as
>   Administrator, and you'll have a good time.

**Orginal answer:**

1. `Ember-cli` has its own server by default so it won't automatically
   appear in `Visual Studio IIS` server, you can redirect ember-cli
   brocoli build output `(dist folder)` to `Visual Studio IIS` for
   hosting, and ember serve for building and livereload.

   2. I think in `VS2013` web type project you need to click `show all files` in solution explorer in
      order to see new files and add them to project.
   3. Make sure to either configure server to start with index.html or
      insert it in url.

Side note:

Care with `tmp, bower and node` folders as VS will hang trying to analyze them

`VS 2013` is not supporting `ecmascript 6` (same as `VS2015RC` ), it won't suport imports and exports as far as i know, so i would advise to use something lighter like sublime until VS team implement it.
-Or dont use `ember-cli`, just `ember` with something like grunt or glup).

I think the most popular approach is to use lightweight editor for ember combined with command line and `Visual Studio` for API codebase

good luck

Answer (score 1):

*What do I have to do to get an ember-cli project running with visual studio?*

It is nearly impossible getting ember-cli and visual studio to play together due to file name length issues.

- The nodejstools enabled VS to know about long file names ( vs will break on ember-cli-babel if not )
- Wasn't able to add ember-cli in in the same mvc5 solution, seems so far to be only as another project but can be in the same solution.
- Thinking you'd want to git ignore the node modules on checkin to TFS ( am sure it will break ). - Then for another dev to get latest would have to run npm update to restore the missing packages.
- Make sure to use the beta npm for better handling of flat files.

You’ll need to first get https://www.visualstudio.com/features/node-js-vs   from nugget installed.

Then create a new project, I chose MVC5 web api.

After this in elevated powershell navigate into the solution folder and run which will make a new ember app named "fire":

`ember new fire`

Get a coffee or a beer or both...

Next right click the solution > add existing website > choose fire folder

Back in powershell run:

`ember server`

Pat yourself on the back and don’t tell M$, they don’t know this yet. If you tell M$ they may not have any reason to fix an ongoing file name length issue but likely won't matter as it seems they have zero interest.

Am using the very latest versions of everything.

Image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3324719/12933286/348c692e-cf3c-11e5-9af0-3b7de8e40203.png

If you made it this far take the rest of the day off!!